# Why must I declare template above each function in a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a template, and I'm a bit new to doing that.  I've noticed that every tutorial I run into declares the template above each function that is implemented.  I'm curious if this is for a reason, if there is a way around it, and how it is useful.

Example: Within some file (we will call it template.h):

```
template <class T> class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(T parameter);
    T getParameter() const;
    void setParameter();
    void doSomethingUseless() const;
private:
    T mParameter;
}


template<class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(T parameter):mParameter{parameter}
    {}

template<class T>
T MyClass<T>::getParameter() const
    {
        return mParameter;
    }

template<class T>
void MyClass<T>::setParameter(T parameter)
    {
        mParameter = parameter;
    }
template<class T>
void MyClass<T>::doSomethingUseless() const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    }
```

- Why must every function be templated if it has nothing to do with the
  template type? (for example, the doSomethingUseless method)
- Why are both the `template<class T>` and the `MyClass<T>` required above each function for this to compile?
- Am I approaching this incorrectly/Is there an easier way to do this?

Anyways, thanks for looking.  As a note, I did not compile the example above, I generalized a different template class that I wrote (without a bunch of busy functions in there)  If there are mistakes, I apologize.

Comment: Wait until both your class and function have their own template arguments :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The member functions of a template class are themselves also templates.  Because of this, they need to be defined with any required template parameters (in your case `T`).  If you did not do this, you might write a function like:

```
void MyClass::memberFunc(T var) {}
```

What is `T` in this case?  There's no T defined within this scope.

So what do people do?  Many code bases will simply define their functions inline with the class.  However others insist on separating them, like you have done.  The unfortunate reality is that it's simply a requirement of the language.

Comment: I understand that the functions themselves are templates of functions for this templated class.  The main question here is why can't it inherit the template of the templated class instead of require each function to carry that same template?

Comment: @MichaelSmith The pedantic answer is simply because the language says so.  C++ is very explicit -- T doesn't exist in the definition context without `template <typename T>`.

Comment: So is there any gained functionality from this pedantic specification?

Comment: @MichaelSmith Functionality, no.  It's likely a language complexity issue.  The function would have to guess all possible templates or concrete types that could match the form.  It's easier to error and require templating.

Answer (score 5):

Member functions of a templated class require `template` so they can specify the class' template, even if the function itself isn't templated.  This is because the class isn't `class MyClass`, but `template<typename T> class MyClass<T>`, but the functions don't know that by default.  Because of this, the compiler needs to know what the class' template parameters are so it can associate the function with the actual class, allowing it to do things such as make the correct version of the member function's `this` pointer, or allow the function to use the class' template parameter list.

This is necessary because templates aren't raw code, they're blueprints for code, which the compiler uses to make the actual code whenever it needs to instantiate or otherwise use them.

```
template<typename T> class MyClass {};

// ...

MyClass<int>  mci; // Compiler creates class "MyClass_int".
MyClass<bool> mcb; // Compiler creates class "MyClass_bool".
```

Due to this, the member functions also need to be templated, so that the compiler will know to use them as code blueprints, too.

```
void MyClass::myFunc() {}
// Compiler thinks this explicitly belongs to class "MyClass".
// Can't be used with MyClass_int or MyClass_bool.

template<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::myFunc() {}
// Compiler knows this belongs to class template "MyClass<T>".
// Can be turned into MyClass_int::myFunc() or MyClass_bool::myFunc().
```

Normally, the template parameter list is defined for the entirety of the class' scope, which allows member functions defined within the class to use the template without explicitly specifying it.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
  public:
    // Every function in here is implicitly "template<typename T>".

    void myInternalFunc(T t) {}
};
```

If the functions are defined outside the class, however, then they no longer have access to the implicit template parameter list, and need to specify it manually.

```
template<typename T>
void MyClass<T>::myExternalFunc(T t) {}
```

Note that this template parameter list is not the *function's*, but the *class'*.  This means that if the function is also templated, it requires a separate template parameter list, which, in all honesty, looks kinda silly.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
    template<typename U>
    void myTemplatedFunc(U u);
}

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void MyClass<T>::myTemplatedFunc(U u) {}
// Class is:     template<typename T> MyClass<T>.
// Function is:  template<typename U> myTemplatedFunc(U u).
```

---

In short: That's not the function's template parameter list, it's the class' template parameter list, used so that the compiler can match the function to the class, and so that the function can act in relation to the class' template parameters (such as having a template parameter as the return type, or taking one as a parameter type).  It's necessary when the function's definition isn't contained within the class' scope, because the function can't inherently see the class' template parameter list outside of the class' scope.

Answer (score 1):

You might (and perhaps should) have a non-template base class that has all the non-template-type-dependent data and methods. That way, not only your declarations will be shorter (and, possibly for some compilers, even the code is shorter), you can have references of the base type and call the non-template-type-dependent functions: `MyClass<int> a(42); const MyBase& b = a; b.doSomethingUseless();`.